# How to set 2 timepicker in 2 different EditText?

Tags: java, android, timepicker

I want to set two `TimePicker` in Two `EditText` but when i select any Time Picker  it will display the same time in Both `EditText`.

for. ex: when i select `Starttime`(EditText) `TimePicker` then it will set automatically in `Endtime`(EditText) too.

Here the code :-

**main.java**

```
starttime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Initialize a new time picker dialog fragment
                DialogFragment dFragment = new TimePickerFragment();

                // Show the time picker dialog fragment
                dFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(),"Time Picker");
                isFromClicked = false;
            }
        });
        endtime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Initialize a new time picker dialog fragment
                DialogFragment dFragment1 = new TimePickerFragment();

                // Show the time picker dialog fragment
                dFragment1.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(),"Time Picker");
                isFromClicked = true;

            }
        });
```

**TimePickerFragment.java**

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        // Get a Calendar instance
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        // Get the current hour and minute
        int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


        // TimePickerDialog Theme : THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT
        TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT,this,hour,minute,false);


        // Return the TimePickerDialog
        return tpd;
    }

  public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute){

        String am_pm = "";

        Calendar datetime = Calendar.getInstance();
        datetime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        datetime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

        if (datetime.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM)
            am_pm = "AM";
        else if (datetime.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.PM)
            am_pm = "PM";

        String strHrsToShow = (datetime.get(Calendar.HOUR) == 0) ?"12":datetime.get(Calendar.HOUR)+"";

        ((EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.start_time)).setText( strHrsToShow+":"+datetime.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+" "+am_pm );

        ((EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.End_time)).setText( strHrsToShow+":"+datetime.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+" "+am_pm);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this class for time picker. I have used it and it works for 2 editexts

```
    public class TimePicker extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
    TextView textView;
    Context context;
    private TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;

    public TimePicker(EditText text, Context context) {
        this.text= textView;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public TimePicker() {
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(android.widget.TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        Time t = new Time(hourOfDay,minute,0);//seconds by default set to zero
        Format formatter;
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String time = formatter.format(t);
          textView.setText(hourOfDay+":"+minute);
    }

}
```

**Usage:**

```
TimePicker timePicker = new TimePicker(editTextName, getActivity());
timePicker.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "Start Time");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's doing exactly what you're telling it to do

```
 ((EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.start_time)).setText( strHrsToShow+":"+datetime.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+" "+am_pm );

 ((EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.End_time)).setText( strHrsToShow+":"+datetime.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+" "+am_pm);
```

Here you set the text of both the EditTexts to the same values

Answer (score 0):

**Do like This**

1. Handle the click event of Both Edit text
2. Onclick open Time picker dialog
3. set the time