# Android Date Picker Fragment - 2 in the same activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker

I'm an absolute beginner, so I'm still learning all the concepts. I'm trying to create an activity with 2 date pickers using fragments. 1 for the hive setup date and 1 for the queen's birthday date - both on 1 activity and both populating separate EditText boxes. Is there anyone that can help me please? Br Iceni Beekeeper.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set 2 timepicker in 2 different EditText?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41998592/how-to-set-2-timepicker-in-2-different-edittext)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updated Answer it Work for me

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {


    public static final String LOGTAG = "APIARYMANAGER";
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static String DATEPICKER_TAG = "";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }


    public void datePickerHiveSetupDate(View view) {

        DatePickerFragmentSetupDate fragment = new DatePickerFragmentSetupDate();
        fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date1");
    }

    public void setHiveQueenBirthdayDate(View view) {

        DatePickerFragmentQueenBDayDate fragment = new DatePickerFragmentQueenBDayDate();

        fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date2");
    }


    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, dayOfMonth);

        if (DATEPICKER_TAG.trim().equals("SETUP_DATE"))
            setHiveSetupDate(cal);
        else
            setHiveQBDayDate(cal);


    }

    public void setHiveSetupDate(final Calendar calendar) {

        final DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.UK);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextHiveSetupDate)).setText(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
    }

    public void setHiveQBDayDate(final Calendar calendar) {

        final DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.UK);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextHiveQueenBirthday)).setText(dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
    }


    public static class DatePickerFragmentSetupDate extends DialogFragment {
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            DATEPICKER_TAG = "SETUP_DATE";
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                    (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getActivity(), year, month, day);
        }


    }


    public static class DatePickerFragmentQueenBDayDate extends DialogFragment {
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            DATEPICKER_TAG = "SETUP_QUEEN_DATE";
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                    (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getActivity(), year, month, day);
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Thank for your quick reply Sachin. I've tried to implement the 2 date pickers based on your code. I'm having a problem with the onDateSet. I only seem to be able to have one method and so both datepickers update the one EditText box.

Comment: how do I post my code please?

Comment: and what you want update two different edittext or one edittext? please explain it.

Comment: thanks Sachin, I've emailed you the code. It's 2 datepickers populating 2 different EditText boxes on the layout. I'm using android:OnClick from the layout to call the method from each EditText box.

Comment: @IceniBeekeeper Try updated Answer

Comment: The tags and the if statement in onDateSet worked a treat. Thanks for your help Sachin.